# django rest framework file upload using json data

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I've defined my model serializer and fileview to upload a file using api.
When I test my API by uploading a file using Postman it works well and the file is getting stored in the media folder.
But in my API I've passed the details in JSON (dictionary format).
Now my code is not picking the file

```
{
file:"C:\users\admin\Desktop\abc.txt",
uploader :"akash"
}
```

When I try this using Postman the file name and uploader is getting stored in the database and the file is stored in the media folder which I've defined in my settings.py file.

My question is how to upload this using JSON format in API POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code. Worked for me.

```
import requests


def upload_file(file, url, token):
    files = {
        "file": file,
    }

    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Token " + token,
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=---WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL"
    }

    response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)

    return response
```

In the views.py:

```
if form.is_valid():
    file = form.cleaned_data['file']

    response = upload_file(file, url, token)
```

Comment: How do you upload file in api ..?? Do you have a browse option to upload a file in api or you upload file by providing fields in jason format.

Comment: The views.py represents the file fetching from serializer...the function represents how to uplaod them via api

Comment: my task is I've a file to upload along with few other fields , now the filename and fields store in db and file is stored at media folder, The same thing is done successfully when I test using postman. But my api doesn't have a browse option to select file from local file system , instead I've a textbox(where I've to upload json content with fields)  to post

Comment: {
file:"C:\users\admin\Desktop\abc.txt",
uploader :"akash"
} , Now how does the api fetch the abc.txt file from local file explorer to upload

Comment: Since you have a rest api that means you will make a post request from somewhere...It can be from reactJs or mobile app or whatever...And for those cases you will have a browse option and fetch data from a form or something...you will grab those info and send it through the api...isn't that the whole point? If that's not then I might failed to understand your problem or you failed to describe it.

Comment: I didn't have any custom made template to my api , I've used the default one which contain media type and content fields . Is it possible to upload a file from content field only or if we need a specific browse option how do I add it to the template

Comment: Someone please help me to add a file upload button to my default restapi, I'm not getting how to add it